# Deployment Failed - You may not modify the permission Reserved for Future Use while editing a Standard Profile

Tags: profile, deployment

I created my packages with all the information eg, fields, screens, RecordTypes and all profiles system. I did deploy "Sandbox1" to "Sandbox2" usually before Summer14. In this Monday, my sandbox is to Summer14 version, created in the same package "Sandbox2" to "Sandbox3" and got the error:

---

**API   Name    Type     Line   Column  Error Message** 
Admin Profile Settings 0      0       You may not modify the permission Reserved for Future Use while editing the Standard Profile

[image: Deployment Error]

---

After this, I cloned the package and removed the Administrator profile, I deploy again and was deployed successfully. 
But, after that I had to enter the Administrator profile in Sandbox3 and enable the field level security and RecordTypes for this profile.

Has anyone seen this error before?

Before the release Summer14, I never see this error before.

[image: Deploy Success]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and after doing a DIFF of the source and target profiles I can see there is a userPermission named ManageUnlistedGroups in the source that is not in the target.  Seems odd since both are Summer '14 (v31) but sometimes different feature activation between environments can cause it.  In my case I removed that permission from the source profile, redeployed and no more error.  BTW, using ant and not changesets so i can modify the profile file once retrieved.

Answer (score -1):

I found this over at the Salesforce Developer site https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AYLCIA4

Comment: Can you add some of the relevant content here? Links go stale over time!